# AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to stream audio and trying to determine the current bit rate of the stream by using this code sample.

```
NSArray *logEvents=playerItem.accessLog.events;
AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *event = (AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *)[logEvents lastObject];
double bitRate=event.observedBitrate;
```

Even after I get my `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent` is `nil`
event

> AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *  nil 0x00000000

I have tried to set up timer and check accessLog after some time of streaming but still got `nil`.

Comment: Are you streaming from a static file, or is it a live stream?

Comment: I'm currently facing lots of limitations when working with live streams. I want to make level metering of a live stream. But what I discovered is that some objects just don't work with live streams. In my case it was `AVAudioMix` if I'm right. I **guess** it is the same reason of limitation which you are facing there